Hash:check() doesn't return result expected Laravel 10
I'm traing to check a password validation without do login in a Laravel 10 project, but the function 'check' returns false, moreover, I can do login with the same password. I Don't know why return false.
Thanks.
    public function recharge_by_client(Request $request){

        $telf      = $request->telf;
        $password  = $request->password;
        $credit    = $request->credit;

        try {
            $client = Client::where('telf', $telf)->first();

            //if verification data is false, returning 0. 
            if ($client && Hash::check($password, $client->password)) {
                \Log::info('Entramos a update');
                HomeHelper::recharge_money($client->id, $credit);
            }else{
                \Log::info('NO entramos a update');
                return ['credit_updated' => 0];
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \Log::info($e->getMessage());
            //A exception has ocurre, returning 0.
            return ['credit_updated' => 0];
        }

        //Returning current credit.
        return ['credit_updated' => Client::find($client->id)->credit];
    }


Looks fine to me. Did you manually update the client password? Or did you generate it with Hash::make()?

what is the result of Hash::check($password, bcrypt($password)) ?

@Hefaz I generated with Has::make().

in addition to the previous comments , can you  test this with a known password
`$knownPassword = 'password123';
$hashed = Hash::make($knownPassword);
if (Hash::check($knownPassword, $hashed)) {
echo 'Password check succeeded.';
} else {
echo 'Password check failed.';
}`

@N69S returns true.

In that case please check the HomeHelper::recharge_money() method to make sure its working as expected.

@elemes I tested the your code and It works well, so I rewrite the password in database and works, so the problem was mine. Thanks.

Great, Glad that was resolved. I will post an answer to this. if you feel it's okay please upvote.
